# Near bezier curve nodes affected when moving a node

Tags: bezier-curves

I have a simple bezier curve. When I move one of the nodes the other nodes near it move too (like I had proportional editing but I don't!). How can I turn this behaviour off so only the node that is selected is moved when I move it? The nodes are not even tracking to each other.

**No proportional editing**, no modifiers, no constraints. Just a simple bezier curve. Here are the settings of it:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtY0j.png or https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtY0j.png

First image below proves that the nodes are not lined up to other node:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6neXS.png or https://i.stack.imgur.com/6neXS.png

Second image shows what happens when I move a node, the other node in the pic sort of rotates towards it:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zH8jL.png or https://i.stack.imgur.com/zH8jL.png

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the 3d view with a before and after of you moving a node?

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: Do you mean the other nodes rotated when you move one of the nodes? if so, this is probably cause by your handle type set to automatic. To solve this, you could select the other nodes and press v to change the handle type to aligned.

Comment: I tried changing the handle type and it happens with all of the options in the v menu. I'll add more pics in the first post if I can now.

Comment: Added new pics. The image uploader on this site is super slow. When I upload directly to imgur I can upload multiple images in couple of seconds. Here the uploader allows uplolading only one image at a time and takes half a minute.

Comment: I figured it out. I needed to have all nodes selected before changing the bezier type in the v menu as it changes it for each node individually and not for the whole curve like I thought.

Comment: So maybe provide an answer - or delete the question?

Comment: Oh sorry, I added the answer below as I understand it. I can only accept it as answer tomorrow at earliest it seems. Thanks to everybody who tried even thought it was me being stupid.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I needed to change my bezier curve type through the v menu. However to successfully change that I needed first to select all bezier handles in edit before pressing v and changing the type for all nodes. This is so because the nodes of a bezier curve object can be set to be different handle types and the v menu only changes the type for the selected nodes, not the curve itself.